# Python 3.4 - Looping through n URLS where n is not fixed

Tags: python, loops, url, web-scraping

What is the easiest way to loop through a series URLs until there are no more results returned?

If the number of URLs is fixed e.g 9,  something like the following code would work

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print('http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?v=list&rptpath=4-380-50-7145-&mcatpath=sports%2fcycling%2fmountain-bikes%2ffull-suspension&page='+ str(i)+'&sort_order=default ')
```

However, the number of URLs is dynamic, and I get a page saying "Sorry, there are currently no listings in this category." when I overshoot.  Example below.

http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?v=list&rptpath=4-380-50-7145-&mcatpath=sports%2fcycling%2fmountain-bikes%2ffull-suspension&page=10&sort_order=default

What is the easiest way to only return  pages with results?

Cheers
Steve

Comment: How about an `if err in response: break` where `err` is the error you mentioned above? Most likely it would be cleaner to use the trademe API though

Comment: I would suggest using their API like a good Internet citizen and not stealing their data: http://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-terms/terms-and-conditions/

Answer (score 1):

```
# count is an iterator that just keeps going
# from itertools import count
# but I'm not going to use it, because you want to set a reasonable limit
# otherwise you'll loop endlessly if your end condition fails

# requests is third party but generally better than the standard libs
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?v=list&rptpath=4-380-50-7145-&mcatpath=sports%2fcycling%2fmountain-bikes%2ffull-suspension&page={}&sort_order=default'

for i in range(1, 30):
    result = requests.get(base_url.format(i))
    if result.status_code != 200:
        break
    content = result.content.decode('utf-8')
    # Note, this is actually quite fragile
    # For example, they have 2 spaces between 'no' and 'listings'
    # so looking for 'no listings' would break
    # for a more robust solution be more clever.
    if 'Sorry, there are currently no' in content:
        break

    # do stuff with your content here
    print(i)
```